# Problema no Click() em um input com Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou desenvolvendo uma automação que faz um choose file numa input, porém quando vou fazer o click no elemento:

```
driver.FindFirstElement(By.Id("chooseFile")).Click();
```

e toda vez me retorna o erro:

```
"Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."
```

Comment: adicione o trecho do seu código HTML

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Neste caso se você clicar no botão ele ira abri a janela de arquivos, para você escolher qual arquivo deseja subir, desta forma esta errada. Tente fazer assim desta forma;

```
       driver.FindFirstElement(By.Id("chooseFile")).SendKeys("c://local do arquivo/arquivo.txt");
```

Em vez clicar você insere o local onde seu arquivo esta armazenado.

até logo!